# SecurityException: Bad applet class name after upgrade to JRE 1.7.0_13

Tags: applet, java

After upgrading to JRE 1.7.0_13 my Applet is not running anymore. I get the following Security Exception:

```
basic: Fortschritts-Listener hinzugefügt: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@25a091
basic: Ausnahme: Bad applet class name.
ExitException[ 3]java.lang.SecurityException: Bad applet class name
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Fortschritts-Listener entfernt: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@25a091
```

The tricky thing is the applet is not loaded from the webserver but installed in JRE lib/ext directory.

I think 'Bad applet class name' has been introduced with _013 because I don't find any information about it. The message does not give me any hint about what to change.

Below is the embedding of the applet in the Web page.

```
<embed table="some param" anzahl="506" 
    type="application/x-java-applet" 
    code="ArtefakteApplet.class" 
    name="artefakteApplet" 
    id="artefakteApplet" 
    height="550" width="1020">
```

Anybody an idea what to do?

Comment: Moving it from lib/ext solves the problem, thanks for the hint. For the moment I can deal with.

I'm just wondering why it does not work anymore and what the error message means.

Comment: Not sure, but 90% I'd say it is related to security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..installed in JRE lib/ext directory.

Don't do that. Sun warned us not to for years before Oracle bought them.

> Anybody an idea what to do?

The first thing to do is move the applet from that location to a public, accessible directory and try it again. Also, don't use the `embed` element. `deployJava.js` is offered as the reliable way to embed an applet.