# Bad applet class name after upgrade to JRE 1.7.0_13

Tags: java, oracle, firefox, xul

I have a Firefox extension loading a Java jar included with the extension itself. I used to use the window.java DOM object so I could do

```
var loader = java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
const myClassRef = java.lang.Class.forName("com.me.program", true, loader);
var myJavaObject = myClassRef.newInstance();
//use LiveConnect to directly call stuff on my object now.
```

in my extension's JS code, where urls was an array containing a `file:///` uri to the jar file.

When Firefox removed window.java, I started embedding an applet in a tag to get a reference to java:

```
<html:embed id ="appletID" type="application/x-java-applet" 
    code="java.applet.Applet"  pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"  MAYSCRIPT="true" width="0" height="0" />

....

var ref = document.getElementById("appletID");
window.java = ref.Packages.java;
```

That doesn't work any more after the update to 7u13, presumably due to the code attribute in the embed tag no longer being supported. What should I do to fix this?

I have tried directly using an `archive=` attribute pointing to my applet, but the problem is that because I'm in a Firefox extension everything turns into `chrome://` uris which the JRE still can't handle, and `file://` uris don't seem to be supported (I get a generic permission denied message).

Comment: Probably related [SecurityException: *Bad applet class name after upgrade to JRE 1.7.0_13*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14702813/418556).  Follow the advice I gave there.

Comment: My jar is not in lib/ext. I can't put the jar somewhere public(where would that be, just at ~?) because it has to be packaged within the xpi of my Firefox extension. It should be accessible where it is anyway, after installation it is in the user's Firefox profile directory under their home directory.

Comment: Your applet is deployed using `embed`.

Comment: What should I use instead? I remember trying applet and object before and neither worked- it's a XUL file overlaying the main Firefox browser.xul frame, not a true HTML document.

Comment: Oh, and I've tried deployJava.js, it doesn't work, gives me "TypeError: document.write is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

This is asked and answered in comments 74 and 75 at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748343 .

In short, the latest Java plugins disallow `code="java.applet.Applet"`. And there seems to be no way to get the plugin to access a jar file in your extension.  The workaround is to put a jar file at a publicly accessible HTTP site; the jar file just needs to contain some trivial applet, like `public class Applet extends java.applet.Applet { }`.  Here is the overlay HTML copied from the Firefox bugzilla comment:

```
<html:div name="appletDiv">
    <html:embed id ="appletID" type="application/x-java-applet" 
        archive="https://mysite.com/applet.jar" code="Applet" 
        pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"  
        MAYSCRIPT="true" width="0" height="0" />     
</html:div>
```